# Version '100.2.1' for 'mongodb-org-tools' was not found

Tags: mongodb

**Background**:

Quoting from the MongoDB Database Tools docs:

> Starting with MongoDB 4.4, mongodump is now released separately from
> the MongoDB Server and uses its own versioning, with an initial
> version of 100.0.0. Previously, mongodump was released alongside the
> MongoDB Server and used matching versioning.

**Problem**:

I'm trying to install the MongoDB Database Tools using Docker/Dockerfile:

```
...

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y gnupg

RUN apt-get install -y wget

RUN wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | apt-key add -

RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org-tools=100.2.1

RUN echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | dpkg --set-selections

...
```

But this line `RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org-tools=100.2.1` is giving me an error:

```
Version '100.2.1' for 'mongodb-org-tools' was not found
```

If I remove `=100.2.1` the tools are installed.

**But I need to specify this specific version (100.2.1) of the MongoDB Database Tools.**

**Question**:

Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work by using:

```
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-database-tools=100.2.1
```

Got the idea from this page:

https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation-linux/

```
sudo dpkg -l mongodb-database-tools

sudo apt install ./mongodb-database-tools-*-100.2.1.deb
```

Can someone from MongoDB please confirm this is the proper way?

Comment: This is in official documentation, I'd say it is the proper way.

Comment: @D.SM Where? Can you please post a link?

Comment: The link you posted is official documentation.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: I do not understand your question now. https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation-linux/ specifies mongodb-database-tools as the package name.